# Count of group by in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I wan to display the first 9 places which have the highest number of reservations. So I must have a count of `$this->db->group_by('t.id_pl')` and then an order by of that counted number.

I've managed to do this but I don't understand where should I put the count :

```
function select_pop ()
{
    $this->db->select( 's.place as place, s.price as price, s.title as title' );            
    $this->db->from('Places AS s'); 
    $this->db->join('Reservations AS t', 't.id_pl= s.place', 'INNER');       
    $this->db->group_by('t.id_pl');
    $this->db->order_by(''); 
    $this->db->limit(9);    
    $result = $this->db->get();
    return $result; 
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you can add count in your select statement like below-

```
$this->db->select('count(t.id_pl) as reservation_count,s.place as place, s.price as price, s.title as title');
```

Then for order by you can use like-

```
$this->db->order_by('reservation_count','DESC');
```

i hope this will help you..